# Не удается подключиться к MySql server, используя EF core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core

Я пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных, используя Entity Framework, но получаю такую ошибку:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'
>
> Inner exception Win32Exception: Не удается найти указанный файл

Моя строка подключения в appsettings.json:

`{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;database=world;uid=root;pwd=root;persistsecurityinfo=True"
  }
}`

Я подключился к базе данных тут: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же я проверил строку подключения в свойствах: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за замечания, добавил все, что мог

Comment: Сдается мне, что вы путаете MySql с Microsoft SQL Server. Если вы собираетесь работать именно c MySql, то должны использовать Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, а ошибка у вас возникает в библиотеке предназначенной к работе с  SQL Server. Про работу с MySql почитайте [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/7.2.php).